# Working css for jquery ganttView in IE7

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins, internet-explorer-7, css-float

Has anyone working css-file to Internet Exlorer 7. Gantt chart is workin correctly on FF,I8,IE9 and Chrome, but in IE7 bars are not floating above grid and don't go inside slider. Does anyone know answer to this? I have tried anything I know.

[Browser differences IE7 and IE9](http://i54.tinypic.com/usn6g.jpg)

https://github.com/thegrubbsian/jquery.ganttView

Comment: Is this problem in ganttView in IE7 right off the box or did it happen when you implemented it into your own page? I cant test it cause I'm on mac, but it does say it there in the github page: "There are minor issues in IE7" ( The problem you are showing in the image doesnt seem that minor, but I felt like i should still make sure if its problem with his code or your modifications maybe. )

Comment: This will be more than just a CSS change. You'll need JavaScript changes to make the ganttView compatible with IE7 standards mode.

Comment: if you can't get this control working, an alternative might be the timeline control: http://www.simile-widgets.org/timeline/

Answer (score 2):

I resolve the problem in IE7 (sure than in all version IE). Only It's neccesary write in file (jquery.ganttView.css):

```
div.ganttview-hzheader-month,
div.ganttview-hzheader-day,
div.ganttview-vtheader,
div.ganttview-vtheader-item-name,
div.ganttview-vtheader-series,
div.ganttview-grid,
div.ganttview-grid-row-cell {
    float: left;
    /* IE problem */
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
...
div.ganttview-slide-container {
    overflow: auto;
    border-left: 1px solid #999;
    /* IE problem */
    position: relative;
}
...
div.ganttview-blocks {
    margin-top: 40px;
    /* IE problem */
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue under IE7 comes from the inline-block CSS attribute applied on a div element. 
This does not work because IE7 accepts only inline elements for the inline-block attribute.

My solution is:
1) on jquery.fn.gantt.js, line 82 replace

```
.append(jQuery('<div class="page-number"/>')
```

by

```
.append(jQuery('<span class="page-number"/>')
```

2) then you will have to fix a little layout side-effect (shift down of the page number) by adding an IE7 hack on your CSS file:

```
/*hack for IE7*/
*+html .fn-gantt .navigate .page-number span {
    top:-5px !important;
}
```